# Show that any continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ induces a map of semisimplicial sets $Sing(X). \rightarrow Sing(Y).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I want to show that any continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ induces a map of semisimplicial sets $Sing(X). \rightarrow Sing(Y).$, but I'm confused about how to do so. I guess the main confusion is that I'm not really sure of how $Sing(X).$ and $Sing(Y)$ might "talk" to each other at all. Presumably we want to compose with $f$.

Moreover, doesn't this map of semisimplicial sets have the structure of a natural transformation?

Comment: How do you precisely define $Sing(X)$?

Comment: Sing(X). := Maps($\Delta^0, X$) $\leftarrow$ Maps($\Delta^1, X$) $\leftarrow \cdots$

Comment: So, what is an element of $Sing(X)$? An infinte dimensional simplex in $X$ basically, or what? Whatsoever, it's quite sure that you only have to compose the given $\Delta^n\to X$ continuous functions with $f:X\to Y$.

Comment: A map of simplicial sets is a natural transformation. Sing is obtained by composing the functor $[n] \mapsto \Delta^n : \Delta^{op} \to Top^{op}$ with the functor $Hom(-, X): Top^{op} \to Set$. Clearly a map $X\to X'$ induces a natural transformation on $Hom$, and therefore on Sing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by semisimplicial set you mean a simplicial set without degeneracies (though, in truth, this works for simplicial sets as well, and other things):

$f$ induces a map $\mathrm{Sing}(X) \to \mathrm{Sing}(Y)$ by composition, just as you stated. You'd need to check that these diagrams commute for face maps $\delta_i : \Delta^n \to \Delta^{n+1}$:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \mathrm{Map}(\Delta^{n+1},X) 
  & \xrightarrow{\delta_i^*} 
  & \mathrm{Map}(\Delta^n, X) \\
  f_* \downarrow  
  &
  & f_* \downarrow \\
  \mathrm{Map}(\Delta^{n+1},Y)
  & \xrightarrow{\delta_i^*} 
  & \mathrm{Map}(\Delta^n, Y)
\end{array}
$$

But that's immediate; $\delta_i^*$ is given by precomposition, and $f_*$ by postcomposition. More specifically, if $\varphi \in \mathrm{Map}(\Delta^{n+1},X)$, then $f_*(\delta_i)^* \varphi = f \circ \varphi \circ \delta_i = \delta_i^*f_* \varphi$.